# Видимость переменной

Tags: javascript

В общем, есть вот это:

```
var countries;
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".city").keyup(function() 
  {
    var search_field = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'searchcity='+ search_field;
    if(search_field=='')
    {
    }
    else
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "autocomplete/search-2.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) { countries = html;}
        //Алерт вот здесь выводит полученные данные
      });
    }
    return false;    
  });
});
// Вот здесь должна быть видна переменная **countries** содержащая в себе полученные данные
//Как это реализовать?
//А здесь алерт не выводит их
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная countries у Вас нигде не объявлена.
Сделайте её глобальной, вставьте эту строку в начало:

`var countries;`

**UPD**

Глобальную переменную использовать можете везде, путем: `window.countries`

**UPD_2**

Исходя из Вашего комментария, могу сказать, что alert(countries) надо вызывать после того, как отработает ajax запрос. Если вызвать до, то переменная будет пустая, так как не выполнилась инициализация.

Вызывать alert(countries) можно либо по событию success, либо по какому-либо действию, например нажатие кнопки.

Comment: Объявил, и тем не менее TypeError: countries is undefined

Comment: @Dikkiy, переменная не будет проинициализирована до тех пор, пока обработчик не вернет данные.

Comment: Что возвращает search-2.php ?

Comment: "['\u0410\u0431\u0430\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439','\u0410\u043a\u0441\u0430\u0439 (\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u043b.)','\u0410\u043a\u0442\u0430\u043d\u044b\u0448','\u0410\u043a\u0442\u0430\u0448','\u0410\u043a\u0442\u044e\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439']"

Comment: Применил сейчас Ваш код на тестовом стенде - все заработало! Только у меня ajax возвращает текст: "Этот текст от ajax запроса". И далее я эту переменную с легкостью юзаю в .js.
Ajax - синхронный.

Comment: Добавил комментарий в код

Comment: Да алертс нужен только для проверки.
Что-то я совсем запутался, какое событие происходит раньше, какое позже :(

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать, что если ты ее там объявишь, она не будет иметь значения. Потому что она будет вызвана, до того как сработает обработчик.

Comment: Где же ее тогда объявить, чтобы все вовремя? :)

Comment: @oldy, то место, где вы ее хотите видеть выполняется при загрузке страницы.  А заполняется переменная только по AJAX-запросу по событию `keyup`. То есть то что вы просите, не имеет смысла, т.к. значение в этом месте в принципе не может существовать.

Comment: Ну это тебе надо читать основы http://www.html.by/threads/986-Urok-prakticheskogo-primenenija-PHP-MySQL
Двумя словами не объяснишь

Comment: Ну вот оно уже, отправил из формы, скрипт php сделал выборку в mysql, прислал в json, и нельзя никак использовать эти данные во благо? :)

Comment: Проблема то вся в JS

Comment: Проблема не в js, а в том, что ты не понимаешь, как эти данные использовать! Уже кучу комментариев написали, что и как сделать. Если тебе даже это не понятно, то тебе надо взять книгу по HTML+PHP+JS(jQuery) и начинать зубрить основы.

Comment: Именно это я имел в виду, что проблема в КОДЕ JS и в том, что переменная там, где надо, не содержит данных, именно поэтому я сюда и пришел, чтобы попросить помощи, чтобы объяснили, но даже те, кто написал кучу комментариев, не смогли дать внятного ответа, как исправить ситуацию.
А учения типа иди в Google и читай книжки известны и без вас.
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: тебе дело говорят, а ты огрызаешься, ты основ не знаешь, поэтому не понимаешь, почему неправильно. Вся логика поле получения данных тут описывается success: function(html) { countries = html; ... сделать что-то ...}